# PyBrain QTable (ActionValueTable) not changing

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, python-2.x, pybrain

I followed a blog post ([here](http://simontechblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/pybrain-reinforcement-learning-tutorial_21.html)) where the author wrote a program with PyBrain to learn how to play Blackjack. He outlines that he is using a Q-Table that was initialized with zeros. At the very end he shows his results (the final Q-Table) after the program played 300 games.

My problem is that when I run his code myself, copied perfectly, the Q-Table does not update. It stays as a table of just zeros forever, even after 1000 hands.

Below is my version of his code, in which I have only added a print statement for the Q-Table.

```
from blackjacktask import BlackjackTask
from blackjackenv import BlackjackEnv
from pybrain.rl.learners.valuebased import ActionValueTable
from pybrain.rl.agents import LearningAgent
from pybrain.rl.learners import Q
from pybrain.rl.experiments import Experiment
from pybrain.rl.explorers import EpsilonGreedyExplorer    
av_table = ActionValueTable(21, 2)
av_table.initialize(0.)
learner = Q(0.5, 0.0)
learner._setExplorer(EpsilonGreedyExplorer(0.0))
agent = LearningAgent(av_table, learner)
env = BlackjackEnv()
task = BlackjackTask(env)
experiment = Experiment(task, agent)
c=0
while True:
    c+=1
    print "Hand "+str(c)+"."
    experiment.doInteractions(1)
    agent.learn()
    print av_table.params.reshape(21,2)
    agent.reset()
```

Other than adding the print statement, I changed the file location of `blackjacktask` and `blackjackenv` to the same folder that the learning program is in, simply because it refused to import it when it was in the `pybrain` folder. My program returns no import errors, and neither does the modules, so I doubt this is the problem.

It is possible that the problem is in the blog poster's modules, which can be found on his post ([here](http://simontechblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/pybrain-reinforcement-learning-tutorial_21.html)).